# JPA's context injection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, persistence

I'm trying to use JPA's Context Injection. Currently my code fails to have the context injected, throwing a NullPointerException:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   learn.spring.dao.ListingDao.findById(ListingDao.java:19)

Below is my code, anyone see what is wrong/missing? Thanks.

**Spring Configuration xml:**

```
<beans ....>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="listingDao" class="learn.spring.dao.ListingDao" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxxx" />
 <property name="username" value="xxxxxx" />
 <property name="password" value="xxxxxx" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="learnSpring" />
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
   <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
   <property name="showSql" value="true" />
   <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
  </bean>
 </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
 <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
...
</beans>
```

**DAO class:**

```
package learn.spring.dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import learn.spring.model.Registration;

@Transactional
public class ListingDao {
 public ListingDao() {}

 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;

 public Registration findById(int id) {
  Query query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Registration r WHERE r.memberId = ?1");
  query.setParameter(1, id);
  return (Registration) query.getSingleResult();
 }
}
```

**peristence.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="learnSpring" />

</persistence>
```

**Class w/ "main" method:**

```
public class Performance {

 public static void main(String[] args){
  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("learn-spring.xml");
  Performer performer = (Performer) context.getBean("musician");
  performer.perform();
  ListingDao listingDao = new ListingDao();
  Registration registration = listingDao.findById(1);
  System.out.println("Member id = " + registration.getMemberId() + " Name = " + registration.getFirstName() + " " + registration.getLastName());
 }

}
```

Comment: And where is UtilistDao.java:19 ?

Comment: and how are you getting and calling the DAO?

Comment: I mis-typed the error in my post, it should be "ListingDao.java:19" 

I'm getting the DAO by manually instantiating "ListingDao" and then on that instance calling the "findById" method (see "Performance" class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `ListingDao` isn't part of the spring context.

All the classes which you want to benefit from the spring's dependecy injection *must be instantiated by spring*. When you instantiate your `ListingDao` with the `new` operator, your object isn't part of the spring context and it doesn't receive an automatic `EntityManager`.

So the solution would be to get the `ListingDao` from the context, like you did with the performer:

```
ListingDao listingDao = (ListingDao) context.getBean("listingDao");
```

As a sidenote - avoid accessing the spring context directly. i.e. avoid lines like the above. Use annotations to inject your dependencies, rather than requesting them, because you are thus turning a Dependency Injection framework into a Service Locator.

Comment: After answering your comment above it hit me that I was circumventing DI by manually instantiating the object... I was so focused on all the other aspects that I overlooked the most obvious.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate ListingDAO, you're doing it outside of the spring context - so spring never gets a chance to wire up the EntityManager.

You should replace:

```
  ListingDao listingDao = new ListingDao();
```

with:

```
  ListingDao listingDao = (ListingDao) context.getBean("listingDao");
```